# What is a conquest this season (12)?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a season journey for this [image]
How do I find these in-game? I see the options with googling, but I don't see any options in-game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On console when I press <kbd>Options</kbd>, then go to Challenges I can switch between season and regular challenges. Conquests are listed in season challenges, see this screenshot:

[image]

This is true for PC as well: press <kbd>Y</kbd> to open achievements. Thanks Mario for confirmation.

Comment: It's the same on PC, after opening the achievements window using Y (or maybe Z, not sure whether it's localized).

Comment: What are these key binds listed as on PC? Key bindings -> what?

Comment: @Asinine looks like it's called 'Show achievements' - see http://www.ign.com/wikis/diablo-3/Key_Binds

Comment: The screenshot I showed was from the Seasonal Achievements...